# PInvoke does not change the object

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2010, pinvoke, dllimport

I have the following PInvoke:(`C` to `C#`)

```
[DllImport("chess_api.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void InitBoard([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 64)]sPiece[] board);
```

On `C`:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void InitBoard(sPiece board[8][8]);
```

In InitBoard function, the values ​​of the matrix changing, but after a call to PInvoke I **do not** see the change.

```
sPiece[] board = new sPiece[64];
InitBoard(board);
//Here the values ​​of the board is still initialized (as before the function call) at default values
```

I tried to change the variable to `ref` (although it already reference) but it stuck the program when the function was called, so I do not think it's the solution.

It took me a while to get here (I'm new to the subject) I'd love to help!

**EDIT:**

sPiece On C:

```
typedef struct Piece
{
    ePieceType PieceType; //enum
    ePlayer Player; //enum
    int IsFirstMove;
} sPiece;
```

sPiece On C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sPiece
{
    public ePieceType PieceType;
    public ePlayer Player;
    public int IsFirstMove;
}
```

Comment: What is `sPiece`? (in C & C#)

Comment: @SLaks. I added this to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you are failing to allocate memory before calling the function.

```
sPiece[] board = new sPiece[64];
InitBoard(board);
```

Declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport("chess_api.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void InitBoard([Out] sPiece[] board);
```

The default marshalling is `[In]`. Although since your struct is blittable, the array you pass is pinned and the call behaves as though it was `[In,Out]`. So I think you could omit `[Out]` if you wished, but it is clearer as written above.

You can add the `UnmanagedType.LPArray` option if you wish but it's not needed.

Comment: Beat me to the punch...well for more information on this type of functionality, MSDN has a good writeup [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21(v=vs.110).aspx)